# Regular custom users able to login to Admin console of Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, admin, django-custom-user

I created a custom user model for Django, and now these regular users are able to login to the Admin console.

My custom user model is extending AbstractBaseUser and my custom user manager sets

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(email=CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email))
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

My custom user model sets this:

```
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='staff status', default=False,
    help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.')
is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='active', default=True,
```

I've checked for each user manually (I don't check this on login) if

```
.is_staff == True
.is_admin == True 
.is_superuser == True
```

but none of these are true and yet the users are still able to login to the admin console.

I'm logging in users like this for the normal login:

```
def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
    """
    Authentication method
    """
    try:
        user = Account.objects.get(email=email)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

I'm using Django's built in authentication for admin console login. I looked at the Django docs and it says I have to

"However, if your User model extends AbstractBaseUser, you’ll need to define a custom ModelAdmin class. It may be possible to subclass the default django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin; however, you’ll need to override any of the definitions that refer to fields on django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser that aren’t on your custom User class."

So when I create a custom ModelAdmin class, do I need to define an authenticate here as well for the admin console?

Comment: I don't understand. Your manager sets them all to true, so they are true. If that's not the case, you'll need to show the code where you are creating users, logging in, and verifying the permissions.

Comment: Updated my question with more info